# Manga where a girl is teleported to a sci-fi world

Tags: story-identification, manga

My memory is pretty blurry, but I remember the beginning decently well. Basically the manga starts out with this sci-fi TV show that the main character finds lame, but both her brother and father are into. Then at school, main character runs into the other future main character, and through some sort of event, the girl gets ahold of this watch that she can't seem to take off. Then at night the watch starts beeping and the girl gets teleported to the sci-fi world where the previous girl is also there. Then it is revealed the TV show is based on the real sci-fi world the girls are in. And basically the series starts from there with the girls balancing school life and the sci-fi life.

Comment: Was the TV show the world the girls were transported to?